# 2D Car Physics for high-speed turning

Tags: 2d, physics

I've been looking at the following page, which has been very helpful: http://www.asawicki.info/Mirror/Car%20Physics%20for%20Games/Car%20Physics%20for%20Games.html but have come into problems with the high speed turning section (about two thirds down the page)

He gives the following function to calculate the slip angle:

[image]

but it looks as if `Vlat` and `Vlong` are both vectors, and I can't see how putting vectors into the `arctan` function or the `sgn` function (which I assume is a function which returns -1 or 1 depending on the value of the sign) works.

The immediately below this he talks about `F n,lat` which he describes as "normalized lateral force for a given slip angle", but I am not sure how to calculate this value.

I'm not sure of any of the maths below this either, but this may be because I have not yet worked out the above bits, so if you wish to explain things below it then I would be grateful but it is not necessary.

I am writing the code using C# and XNA if this is important.

Thanks

Comment: The v_lat and v_long are presumably the lateral and longitudinal *components* of the velocity vector. Likewise F_{n,lat} would be the lateral component of the normalized Force vector.

Comment: You might have a bit more luck on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, people there are more likely to have encountered things like this.

Comment: @dmckee but then it would not make sense to get the magnitude of `v long` in the denominator.

Comment: That || is not for magnitude, it is for absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

From the page

> The velocity vector of the wheel has angle alpha relative to the direction in which the wheel can roll. We can split the velocity vector v up into two component vectors. The longtitudinal vector has magnitude cos(alpha) * v. Movement in this direction corresponds to the rolling motion of the wheel. The lateral vector has magnitude sin(alpha) * v and causes a resistance force in the opposite direction: the cornering force.

So `Vlong` is the velocity in the direction the wheel is facing and `Vlat` is the velocity perpendicular the direction the wheel is facing.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this answer does not help me for I am not too sure on how to calculate these things.

Comment: From a comment on the question I have realised that `vLat` and `vLong` are the `X` and `Y` components of the car's velocity, respectively. This was me getting confused about things. I still am not sure about what `F n,lat` is however.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is still relevant.

Velocity. Velocities you have do not seem to be vectors, because

a) they are actually components of a vector see wikipedia page for more reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_angle.

b) you have an expression of addition/subtraction of your v_lat and a scalar, so v_lat cannot be vector by any means.

So don't worry about them, they are old friend scalars and you can work with them as usual.

Force. From the webpage you quoted:

> The longtitudinal force has (as good as) a linear dependency on load,
>   we saw that earlier when we dicussed weight transfer.  So instead of
>   plotting a curve for each particular load value, we can just create
>   one normalized curve by dividing the force by the load.

So the normalisation is performed by dividing F_long (from your post I assume that you are able to calculate this) by the load (you should have this somewhere in conditions).

Anyway, this is my vision of the problem. Hope it was useful.